# FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:) returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, ios-app-group

I am using app groups to share information between an ios app and a files extention.
The problem here however is that `FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.my.group.id.shared")` does return `nil` indicating that the app group identifier is invalid.

What is strange about this is that I should have configured the app group correctly. I did it in xCode Version 11.3 (11C29) in the "signing and capabilities" tab. The app group is not colored in red and it is also added in the extention. I also checked the release and debug configuration.

I have already tried creating a new app group with the same result.

Strange enough it is possible for `NSUserDefaults` to access the same suite: `UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.my.group.id.shared")`

Does anyone here have experiences with this and can maybe help?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I'm having the same issue. were you able to figure this out?

Comment: No I have not found a solution yet.